# How to find a single element in a set that isn't in another using set comprehension

Tags: python, set

I have two sets, set1 and set2... Almost all elements in both sets are the same except for one element.

Supporting code is below:

```
set1 = {'dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'monkey'}
set2 = {'dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'gorilla'}
```

I am trying to get the unique element of each set into its own variable using set comprehension.

```
set1Unique = 'monkey'
set2Unique = 'gorilla'
```

I have got it working by doing the following but it is not what is required, using set comprehension is.

```
    set1UniqueElements = set1 - set2
    set1Unique = list(set1UniqueElements)[0]
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a set comprehension for this? Is it an external constraint imposed e.g. for a [homework question, job screening question etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)? A question like this can't really be answered aside from just giving a few lines of code, and plagiarism is a serious academic offense. If you want to learn general technique with set comprehensions, please [try to research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique item is the element in the set that's not in the other set.  Hence:

```
>>> cat = 'cat'
>>> set1 = {'dog', cat, 'turtle', 'monkey'}
>>> set2 = {'dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'gorilla'}
>>> {e for e in set2 if e not in set1}
{'gorilla'}
>>> {e for e in set1 if e not in set2}
{'monkey'}
```

To get an arbitrary element from the set (converting a single-element set to that single element on its own) you can use `set.pop()`:

```
>>> {e for e in set1 if e not in set2}.pop()
'monkey'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are guaranteed that there is at least one element in set2 that is not in set1, and you're only looking for the first such element:

```
next(e for e in set2 if e not in set1)
```

This code stops as soon as it find any element in `set2` not in `set1`.

Answer (score -1):

Since there is only a single unique element, it is possible to use packing to access the elements directly:

```
[set1Unique] = set1 - set2
[set2Unique] = set2 - set1
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use this:

```
ex = set1 ^ set2
set1unique = ex & set1
set2unique = ex & set2

print(set1unique)
print(set2unique)
```

You can can compute ex inside the setNunique formulas. It saves a line, but you compute ex twice.